# what speed must a bullet be fired at to turn into gas when hitting a steal plate

Tags: experimental-physics, building-physics

what speed must a bullet be fired at to turn into gas when hitting a steel plate.

from watching this [video](https://9gag.com/gag/ajVmzAq) on 9gag, i see that the bullet almost turns into liquid, what speed would it need to hit it to turn into a gas?

Comment: What material? makes a difference...

Comment: If you consult the phase diagram of lead, you may find your answer... If you allow for any material, shoot the breeze to begin with...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to heat it up to the vaporisation temperature and you have also 2 phase changes, from solid to liquid and then from liquid to gas. If you assume kinetic energy is converted into heat and some loses, the speed $v$ comes up from equilibrium:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot m \cdot v^2 = m\cdot c_p \cdot \Delta T+ m\cdot \Delta H_{fus} + m\cdot \Delta H_{vap} + H_{losses}$$

where:

- $m$ is bullet mass
- $c_p$ is heat capacity
- $\Delta T$ is temperature difference between vaporisation and initial temperature
- $\Delta H_{fus}$ and $\Delta H_{vap}$ are latent heats of fusion and vaporisation
- $H_{losses}$ represents losses to air and steel plate

From this, the minimum speed $v_{min}$ (ignoring losses) will be:

$$v_{min} = \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{c_p \cdot \Delta T+ \Delta H_{fus} + \Delta H_{vap}}$$

Here are minimum speeds for lead and iron:

| substance | liquefaction speed m/s (km/h) | vaporisation speed m/s (km/h) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lead | 161.02 (579.67) | 678.89 (2444) |
| iron | 322.22 (1160) | 922.11 (3319.6) |

Comment: If the other losses are included then v will be reduced so did you mean v will be the maximum from that expression?

Comment: @SolarMike Other loses would have to be included in the right side of the equation and they would effectively take from the initial kinetic energy, so the actual speed would be higher.